# Evaluate $\int_0^3\sqrt{9-x^2}dx$ using areas

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

Evaluate $\int_0^3\sqrt{9-x^2}dx$ using areas

If I divide $[0,3]$ into $n$ equal partitions, and chose the height of the partition as the right end point, then

$$\int_0^3\sqrt{9-x^2}dx=\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{9-k^2}\cdot \frac{3}{n}$$

But the riemann sum is difficult to evaluate. How should I choose my partition to make the sum easier to solve?

Comment: If you want to evaluate the integral using areas you must have in mind that your integral is $1/4$ of the area of a circle of radius $3.$

Comment: @mfl so integration using area means i have to use geometry and not the riemann sum?

Comment: I understand it in that way from the title of your question. But I am not sure if you were asked that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually $f(x) = \sqrt{9-x^2}$ for $x \in [0,3]$ represents a circle of radius $3$ restricted in the first quadrant. This is because the implicit equation of the circle is $x^2 + y^2 = 3^2 \implies y = \pm \sqrt{9-x^2}$. Therefore the integral is simply the area of the quarter of the circle : $9\pi/4$.